# Referring to sourced ARM variables in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create AKS by using terraform, In `service principle` block we need to pass `client_id` and `client_secret`. Terraform has the ability to read env variables and source them if they are prepended as TF_VAR_name.

Terraform also mentioned that for [provider block](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/guides/service_principal_client_secret.html) we can export the client related variables as `ARM_CLIENT_name`. So my question is how to use those ARM variables for provisioning my AKS.

Right now I am doing like this

```
  - export ARM_CLIENT_ID=$AZ_USERNAME
  - export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=$AZ_PASSWORD
  - export ARM_TENANT_ID=$AZ_TENANT
  - export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=AZ_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
```

If I can't refer to above env variables then I should do

```
 - export ARM_CLIENT_ID=$AZ_USERNAME
 - export TF_VAR_client_id=$AZ_PASSWORD
 - export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=$AZ_PASSWORD
 - export TF_VAR_client_secret=$AZ_PASSWORD
 - export ARM_TENANT_ID=$AZ_TENANT
 - export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=AZ_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
```

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If yes, please accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you display in the question are two different situations.

One is that the authentications for Azure providers. It can quote the necessary input from the environment variables such as `ARM_CLIENT_ID=$AZ_USERNAME`, `ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=$AZ_PASSWORD`, `ARM_TENANT_ID` and `ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID`.

Another one is to quote the normal variables. You can export all the variables you need as environment variables with the prefix `TF_VAR_`, but another thing you need to do is that you also need to define the variables inside the Terraform file. As it shows [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#environment-variables):

> As a fallback for the other ways of defining variables, Terraform
>   searches the environment of its own process for environment variables
>   named TF_VAR_ followed by the name of a declared variable.

For example, if you want to quote the variable `aksname` from the environment variable, then you need to do two things:

1. export the environment variable `aksname` with a prefix `TF_VAR_`:

`export TF_VAR_aksname=example-aks`

2. define the variable `aksname` inside the Terraform file and quote it, here I just quote it in the output block:

```
variable "aksname" {}

output "aks_name" {
  value = "${var.aksname}"
}
```

Then the output will like this:

[image]